# How to find an element in a table without repeater

Tags: javascript, html, jasmine, protractor

[image: HTML]

What's the best method to find the yellow-highlighted text in the above HTML?
Is there a way to find a text on the page in a specific tag?

I need to perform a click on this element, which inturn opens up the table `15112-1-table-ssrc_2210456055_recv`

I tried `by.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'ssrc_+\w+_recv')]");` but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know the `ssrc_something_recv` text beforehand:

```
var summary = element(by.xpath("//summary[starts-with(., 'ssrc_') and contains(., '_recv')]"));
summary.click();
```

Now, to locate the related `table`, you can use the `following-sibling` axis:

```
var table = summary.element(by.xpath("following-sibling::table"));
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response @Alecxe, in `ssrc_2210456055_recv`, i only know the `ssrc_ _recv` before hand.. the numeric value is randomly generated.
Would using a RegEx `by.xpath("//summary[. = 'ssrc_+\w+_recv']")`work?

Comment: @CodeRJ unfortunately, you cannot use regular expressions in xpaths in selenium webdriver as of today, use the `starts-with` and `contains()`, updated the answer, check it out.